# How do i get total cart count in magento?

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1.8, cart

I want to get total cart count it means how many times a particular product was added to cart. I know I have to use statement like this:

```
$Products = Mage::getResourceModel('reports/product_collection')->AddCartsCount();
```

But not getting how to approach from here. please help me to get total cart count of a product.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$collection = Mage::getResourceModel('reports/quote_collection');
$collection->prepareForProductsInCarts()
    ->setSelectCountSqlType(Mage_Reports_Model_Resource_Quote_Collection::SELECT_COUNT_SQL_TYPE_CART);
if($collection->getSize()) {
    echo '<pre>';
    foreach($collection as $cart) {
        echo 'Product Name =>: '.$cart->getName();
        echo '<br>';
        echo 'Cart Count =>: '.$cart->getCarts();
        echo '<br>';
        echo '<br>';
    }   
}
```

Comment: it worked but I want to show cart count for products that are in the category not overall cart count collection for all products. Thanks

Comment: are need all product cart count right? Or need per category cart count?

Comment: No Success, is there anyway that we can pass product id in to the collection object so that we can get cart count based on product id. Thanks